# display: inline-block not working correctly

Tags: html, css, display

I have two divs which I would like to have placed next to each other. This works when I give both divs the `display: inline-block;` property, but once I add a `<p>` tag into one of the divs the placement of that div goes out of whack. This is what i'm working with:

HTML:

```
<div class = "icon_container">
    <button><img src="images/favorite.png" class = "profile_icons"/></button><p>1234</p>
</div>
<div class = "icon_container">
    <button><img src="images/tool.png" class = "profile_icons"/></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon_container {
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qLysghjf/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qLysghjf/1/ this is what you want?

Comment: Just need to make the <p> : display: inline block and remove the margin-top https://jsfiddle.net/8m29n7f4/1/

Comment: @Just code I'm sorry, I don't see any difference between your fiddle and mine. What did you change? It still shows my original code in your link

Comment: @Potatoes I apologize, but I meant to say in my question that I do still want the p tag below the image. Your solution does fix the alignment problem, but at the cost of the p tag being next to the image instead of underneath. I should've made myself more clear, sorry about that :/

Comment: @NickMartini my bad https://jsfiddle.net/qLysghjf/5/

Comment: @Justcode That works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to this [post](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) by @robertnyman, to make `inline-block` element vertically align right, it needs `vertical-align: top;`. I had tried in your fiddle get the result as:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLysghjf/3/

So the css is:

```
.icon_container {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I can help.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a vertical align to your icon_container class:

```
.icon_container {
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qLysghjf/2/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Nick, just curious why you un-accepted my answer, but glad I could help!

Comment: Hey @jdherder , your answer was totally correct, but I saw that another poster had included a source for his answer so I accepted his answer instead. I figured that if someone stumbles upon this question that they might want to do some extra digging by viewing the source. I hope you don't take it personally because your answer was absolutely correct and helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please add **`float:left`**  in **`.icon_container`** css class. Hope this will work